# I am trying to convert an xml file into a csv file. Below is what i have tried so far

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def xml_to_csv(path):
    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for member in root.findall('object'):
        value = (root.find('filename').text,
                 int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                 int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                 member[0].text,
                 int(member[4][0].text),
                 int(member[4][1].text),
                 int(member[4][2].text),
                 int(member[4][3].text)
                 )
        xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df


def main():
    image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "/images")
    xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
    xml_df.to_csv('baby_labels.csv', index=None)
    print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')

main()
```

after successfully running this command and i got baby_labels.csv file , but after opening this file nothing data is written means empty. can u help me out

Comment: Mind your indents! The code should all be in a code block with extra spaces removed. Makes it easier for us to read.

Comment: Also, add a small example xml file for us to try. You could even pare this all down to just a couple of rows and columns.